# Continuity of the function $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}[\lim\limits_{t\to 0}[\frac{\sin^2 (n!\pi x)}{\sin^2(n! \pi x)+t^2}]] $, $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

[image]

Consider the Question.  I think that f(x)=1 $\forall x \in \mathbb {R}$.

Reason: As t $\to$ 0 , $[\frac{\sin^2 (n!\pi x)}{\sin^2(n! \pi x)+t^2}]$   $\to[\frac{\sin^2 (n!\pi x)}{\sin^2(n! \pi x)}]= 1$.

So it is differentiable in $\mathbb R$.
But the explanation given is the following.

[image]

Now my questions are as follows:

1) Am I right? if not, in what way?

2) Whether the explanation given in the picture is correct?

**3)Can I interchange Limits? if So under what conditions.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The explanation given in figure is correct and that's the way to go.

Comment: It seems that, if we interchange the limits, it does not exist the limit $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin^2(n!\pi x)}{\sin^2(n!\pi x)+t^2}$ for any $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q.\;$ Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you mention does not exists when $\sin\left(n! \pi x\right)=0$ so your thoughts are not bad, but are not true for all $x$.
If $n!x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then you are right
$$
\frac{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)}{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)+t^2} \underset{t \rightarrow 0}{\sim}\frac{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)}{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)}=1
$$
However if $n!x \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $n!x=N_n$ then

$$\sin\left(n! \pi x\right)=\sin\left(N_n \pi \right)=0$$

Hence $f(x)=0$ if $n!x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

You can change limits when the sequence $$f_n(t)=\displaystyle \frac{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)}{\sin^2\left(n! \pi x \right)+t^2}$$
converges uniformly on $I$ and if $t \in \overline{I}$.

Comment: so ,the explanation given is correct?

Comment: Yes. But yours for case II looks good to me too. But only in case II not for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is incorrect. For any fixed $n,$ if $\sin(n!\pi x) = 0,$ then for any $t\ne 0,$ the expression equals $0/(0+t^2)=0.$ Thus the limit as $t\to 0$ is $0.$ So the double limit in case I is $0$ as claimed.

Comment: That's what it is said.

Comment: How can we prove that for any rational $sin(n!\pi x) = 0$.