# Find points of discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In this question

[Continuity of the function $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}[\lim\limits_{t\to 0}[\frac{\sin^2 (n!\pi x)}{\sin^2(n! \pi x)+t^2}]] $, $x \in \mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607932/continuity-of-the-function-fx-lim-limits-n-to-infty-lim-limits-t-to-0)

We're required to find points at which $f(x)$ is discontinuous.

Now in this case when $x \in \mathbb Z$, then $\sin^2(n!\pi x) = 0\quad\therefore\quad f(x) = 0$

And for a set of rationals too $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sin^2(n!\pi x) = 0 \quad when \quad n!x \in \mathbb Z$.

I'm not sure how we can rigorously prove that for any $x \in \mathbb Q$.