# Discontinuity of $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 (n!πx)}{t^2+\sin^2 (n!πx)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm a  studying discontinuity of the function
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 (n!πx)}{t^2+\sin^2 (n!πx)}\right)$$

The book says it is the Dirichlet's function.

My approch is ,if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$ then $0\lt \sin^2 (n!πx)\lt 1\implies f(x)=1$

But I'm not able to show that $f(x)=0$ when $x\in \mathbb{Q}$

One idea I got from the internet that interchanging the limits, then $n!πx$ will be an integer ultimately giving 0 -sequence which will give the desired value at the irrationals.

Now my question is ,Is this "limits interchanging"always allowed?
, if not ,under which conditions it is allowed..

Comment: When $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ will be more, then denominator of $x$, then ..

Comment: Hint. If $x=p/q$ with $q\in \mathbb{N}^+$ then $n!x$ is an integer for $n\geq q$.

Comment: Found a duplicate post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607932/continuity-of-the-function-fx-lim-limits-n-to-infty-lim-limits-t-to-0?noredirect=1  via [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3D%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Clim_%7Bt%5Cto%200%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%5E2%20(n!%CF%80x)%7D%7Bt%5E2%2B%5Csin%5E2%20(n!%CF%80x)%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, there exists coprime numbers $p,q$ such that $x = p/q.$ Note that for $n > q$,
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(n! \pi x)}{t^2 + \sin^2(n!\pi x)} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{0}{t^2 + 0} = 0.$$
This is because $n!\cdot \frac{p}{q}$ will be an integer.

Now, since for all $n > q$, the inner expression is 0, we obtain $f(x) = 0$ for $x = p/q$.

Comment: How this interchanging the limits worked here, I mean what is the condition  under which I can swap the limits..

Comment: I didn't interchange the limits. I took an arbitrary $n > q$ and evaluated the inner limit to be 0. Then I took the limit of my inner result as $n \to \infty$, which is 0.